# How to use Czech Macintosh keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout

I just installed ubuntu on my Mac. However, I found out there is no "Czech (Macintosh)" keyboard, despite there being "Dutch (Macintosh)", "German (Macintosh)" and so on.

Since I am a programmer, I want to have all the special letters like ` on the same place they are actually on the keyboard (since I am so used to them).

Is there a possibility to install Czech Macintosh keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but with russian keyboard layout.
I have found some keyboard layout files at /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru and modifying it for my MacBook Pro keyboard. Since you programmer too, I think it is not so hard to realize such a solution.
You can find examples for Mac keyboard from Macish Keyboard layouts you mentioned in question.

Since you using Mac Pro or Mac mini(Not MacBook/Laptop) then you can just attach PC keyboard and it is best sulution. But for me it is not work when Iḿ taking my MacBook Pro out of home.